# House Robber Problem Variation with Risk/Cost to Rob Each House

Tags: dynamic-programming

I came across a modification of the classic house robber problem where there is a cost to robbing each house, and we want to maximize the amount robbed using the array (exactly as in the original problem) but with the added constraint that we now have some array C, and C[i] is the cost to rob a particular house.  We don't want to exceed some total budget B.  Solve the house robber problem with the original array (call it A), B, and C passed as arguments.

I think that we can solve this using DP and a 2-D matrix (n × B), where are solving for the recurrence $$D[i, j] = \max\{(D[i-2, j + C[i]] + A[i]), D[i-1, j]\}$$
but that's as far as I have gotten (my recurrence could be off).